# increase the size of textArea programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am able to increase the size of textarea according to Number of lines, but supose I did not press enter and simply enter text then it does not work and size of textarea does not work. See the following fiddle.

```js
$("textarea").on("keyup", function($event) {
        this.rows = (this.value.split("\n").length||1);
        var thisTextArea = $event.currentTarget;
                if (thisTextArea.value.split("\n").length > 5) {
                    thisTextArea.rows = (thisTextArea.value.split("\n").length);
                    $(thisTextArea).css("overflow-y","hidden");
                    if (thisTextArea.rows > 15) {
                        $(thisTextArea).css("overflow-y","scroll");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    thisTextArea.rows = 6;
                    $(thisTextArea).css("overflow-y","hidden");
                }
    });
```

```html
<textarea rows="5"></textarea>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0vh90ka4/1/)

Comment: I don't want to put extra js files.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `div` or other tag with attribute `contenteditable='true'`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document)
    .one('focus.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0,
            rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

**html**

```
<textarea rows="5"class='autoExpand'></textarea>
```

**css**

```
textarea{  
  display:block;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  overflow:hidden;

  padding:10px;
  width:250px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-radius:8px;
  border:6px solid #556677;
}
```

[link here](http://jsfiddle.net/0m63v0wc/)

Comment: Same issue when we text a long line without pressing the Enter Key it does not work.

Comment: check again the link and press text more long time.it is tested

Comment: press at least 10 line

Comment: it is calculating the scroll height and increase heights by row depending on it.

Comment: $(document)
    .one(

it is on or one?

Answer (score 2):

Finalaly I have done this way.
See following Link.

```
$("textarea").on("keyup",function($event) {
                 var textarea = $event.currentTarget;

    if (textarea.scrollHeight > 305) {
            textarea.style.height = "1px";
    textarea.style.height = (3+textarea.scrollHeight)+"px";
        $(textarea).css("overflow-y","scroll");

    }
    else if (textarea.scrollHeight > 105){
        $(textarea).css("overflow-y","hidden");
        textarea.style.height = "1px";
        textarea.style.height = (3+textarea.scrollHeight)+"px";
    }
                 });
$("textarea").on("focus",function($event) {
    var textarea = $event.currentTarget;
        if (textarea.scrollHeight > 105) {
            //textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight;
            $(textarea).css("height",textarea.scrollHeight);
            if(textarea.scrollHeight > 305) {
            $(textarea).css("overflow-y","scroll");
            }
        }
    $( "textarea" ).unbind("focus");

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwkw3a2r/1/

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mbklein/jquery-elastic/blob/master/index.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').elastic();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Demo - Elastic</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbklein/jquery-elastic/master/dependencies/screen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="form">
    <p>
      <label>Fill the textarea to make it grow</label>
      <span class="w">
     <textarea class="input">This textarea is going to grow when you fill it with text. Just type a few more words in it and you will see.</textarea>
    </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbklein/jquery-elastic/master/jquery.elastic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is showing scroll, text is going upside not the textarea is expanding.

Comment: Please download and run it , because scripts are not loading

Answer (score 0):

Update html

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="15"></textarea>
```

Use this js snippet

```
$("textarea").on("keyup", function($event) {
    var textarea = $(this);
    var text = textarea.val();
    var lines = text.split(/\r*\n/);
    var cols = textarea.attr('cols');
    var TOTAL_LINES = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        TOTAL_LINES += Math.ceil(lines[i].length/cols);
    }    
    console.log(TOTAL_LINES);
    if (TOTAL_LINES > 5) {
        textarea.attr('rows', TOTAL_LINES);
        textarea.css("overflow-y","hidden");
        if (TOTAL_LINES > 15) {
            textarea.css("overflow-y","scroll");
        }
    } else {
       textarea.attr('rows', 6);
        textarea.css("overflow-y","hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is we can't count auto line breaks. to resolve this you need to set cols attribute to textarea and devide charecters of textarea to number of columns.

check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ashish1bhagat/0vh90ka4/4/

Comment: it's working fine, but first line become hide when no. of line exceed and automatically show again.

Comment: And if the size of character is too big that it contain characters less than the Number of the columns...?

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```js
$('textarea').val('Some\nSample\nText')

$('textarea').each(itm => {
  $('body').find('textarea').eq(itm).css('height', 'auto');
  $('body').find('textarea').eq(itm).css('height', $('textarea')[itm].scrollHeight + 'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="TextArea"></textarea>
```